# How the values of count += countPaths(sp + i, ep) are being calculated?

Tags: java, counting

The output of the code is 4. The functions are being called recursively in the loop. How the value of count += countPaths(sp + i, ep) bieng calcualted? How the functions are being called recursively? What will be the stack frame?

```
// Count the number of paths possible from start point to end point in game board
public class CountPaths {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(countPaths(0, 3));
    }

    private static int countPaths(int sp, int ep) {
        if (sp == ep) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (sp > ep) {
            return 0;
        }

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6 ; i++) {
            count += countPaths(sp + i, ep);
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

I tried making the dry run of the code to understand its working, the stack frame and especially how the value is being calculated? But I can not come up with this, so I need guidance in these aspects.

Comment: The `countPaths()` method is called a [Recursive Method](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_recursion.asp)  which means that the method calls itself...from within itself to carry out the necessary calculations. Overall, this is called **Recursion**. If you run and *step* through the code with your IDE's debugger, you will see exactly how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear what you are asking for.  The following is a walkthrough of how the given execution produces the value 4.

The initial state for the call from `main` will pass the terminal states and go to the loop which makes 6 recursive calls and returns their sum.  So it is doing the following (simplified method name to `x` for readability):

```
x(0,3) = x(1,3) + x(2,3) + x(3,3) + x(4,3) + x(5,3) + x(6,3)
```

Look at your terminal conditions - i.e. the cases where you do no recursion.

```
if (sp == ep) {
  return 1;
}

if (sp > ep) {
  return 0;
}
```

The terminal conditions define the following cases for the given execution:

```
x(4+,3) = 0
x(3,3) = 1
```

Given this knowledge we can simplify our base case to the following:

```
x(0,3) = x(1,3) + x(2,3) + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0
       = x(1,3) + x(2,3) + 1
```

Do a similar exercise with these two cases (i.e. `x(1,3)`, `x(2,3)`).

```
x(1,3) = x(2,3) + x(3,3) + x(4,3) + x(5,3) + x(6,3) + (7,3)
       = x(2,3) + 1 +  0 + 0 + 0 + 0
       = x(2,3) + 1

x(2,3) = x(3,3) + x(4,3) + x(5,3) + x(6,3) + x(7,3) + x(8,3)
       = 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0
       = 1
```

We solved x(2,3) so we substitute that back into x(0,3) and  x(1,3)...

```
x(0,3) = x(1,3) + x(2,3) + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0
       = x(1,3) + 1 + 1
       = x(1,3) + 2
x(1,3) = x(2,3) + x(3,3) + x(4,3) + x(5,3) + x(6,3) + (7,3)
       = x(2,3) + 1 +  0 + 0 + 0 + 0
       = 1 + 1 + 0...
       = 2
```

We solved x(1,3) so we can substitute that back into x(0,3) and we're done..

```
x(0,3) = x(1,3) + x(2,3) + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0
       = 2 + 1 + 1
       = 4
```